# Wind energy data in India

Tags: data-request, geospatial, weather, energy, india

I am looking for wind energy data (they can be wind speed at any height or wind energy potential) for India in a GIS format.

Like the data displayed the link below: http://www.arcgis.com/apps/OnePane/basicviewer/index.html?appid=f03b21b359964374a1d4c274de254f26

Answer (score 5):

The [MERRA](http://gmao.gsfc.nasa.gov/research/merra/) dataset has data for the world from 1979 to date. It updates frequently.

You can get the data as HDF or NETCDF. If your GIS package doesn't read those, there will be translation packages around the web to convert them into a suitable format.

You'll want the U- and V- wind data. You might want pressure too. And possibly even turbulence data.

And I highly recommend [the paper by Cannon et al on analysing the MERRA data for wind energy simulation](http://www.met.reading.ac.uk/~energymet/data/Cannon2015/).

You might also be interested in the [CFSR](http://cfs.ncep.noaa.gov/cfsr/) data, which runs 1979-2010: in connection with using this paper for wind energy simulation, see [this paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.renene.2014.12.025) by Sharp et al.

Comment: +1 for the links to papers (Cannon: 10.1127/metz/2016/0751).
Are there other papers you'd recommend ?
Also, would you have a minute to look at this old question
[Wind energy vs. wind speed](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/4412/wind-energy-vs-wind-speed)
? Thanks