# Sensor data from wind turbines

Tags: data-request, energy, sensors

Are there any data sets available for sensors of wind turbines? I'm looking for *sensor* data off the actual wind turbines, not the wind speed or energy data. This is for a preventative maintenance use case (i.e., pulling sensor data off the wind turbines to detect any mechanical issues and implement predictive maintenance).

I'm also curious how much data is generated per day from all the sensors on these turbines.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wind farm energy vs. wind speed](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/4412/wind-farm-energy-vs-wind-speed) - if it's not duplicate, can you please edit the question?

Comment: @philshem Edited my question

Comment: Relevant - [Renewables: Share Data on Wind Energy](http://www.nature.com/news/renewables-share-data-on-wind-energy-1.19104#/b1)

Comment: This is probably the person to contact and ask about available datasets http://user.engineering.uiowa.edu/~ankusiak

Comment: Have you found any data?

Comment: @philshem I have not. I contacted the individual about the data set in your Mar 23 comment and they were not able to help

Comment: This user is referencing wind speed measured on the tower (mast). So far no response in asking for the data. http://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/7542/1511

Comment: These datasets are hard to find as a lot of sensible information from the manufacturer and from the owner of the WTG can be extracted. There are some public sites that provide some information and, maybe, under request they can provide more detailed information: http://www.noordzeewind.nl/en/knowledge/reportsdata/

Comment: I'm also very interested in this.  (actually for similar same reasons, testing predictive algorithms ) .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Engie Group has just published operational data of one of its wind farms under the Open License 2.0 of Etalab. See here: https://opendata-renewables.engie.com/

Comment: Thanks for this answer Paul. An open dataset like this has definitely been lacking.

Comment: Sadly, it seems that engie stopped hosting the La Haute Borne data set publicly - or does anyone know how to find it?