# Understanding wind speed data

Tags: time-series, energy

I am trying to understand wind speed as time series from a mast (tower). The names of the fields are v80a, v80b, v60a, v60b etc. Now I do know that v80 is the wind speed at 80 meters. But why use v80a and v80b etc.?

Can you please explain this or point me to some resources that provide an explanation?

Comment: To make a decent guess, probably we need a sample of the data, or a more detailed explanation of the source or program used.

Comment: Can you share where you obtained this data set?

Answer (score 2):

I'll make a guess anyway.

**a** and **b** are the measurements from two [anemometers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anemometer), either used for redundancy (i.e. machine failure or numerical error), or for different sensitivity/directionality.

Comment: Nice guess. Possibly at different distances, eg. using LIDAR

Comment: Not necessary at different distances, you can install several anemometers at the same height but at different boom orientations. E.g.: http://www.sgurrenergy.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/sgurrmetmast.jpg