# Spatial Wind Direction/Speed Data

Tags: geospatial, weather, africa

Does anybody know of a source for wind data ~04 - 14 for E. Africa or a larger area. I have looked at a number of sources but have not found anything for these consecutive years.

Comment: I think this is a similiar question: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/146684/acquiring-global-wind-data

Comment: Have a look here: http://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/10380/14881

Answer (score 2):

The European Centre for Medium Range Weather Forecasts hosts a database with this information here: http://apps.ecmwf.int/datasets/data/interim-full-daily/levtype=sfc/

You'll want the `10 metre U wind component` and the `10 metre V wind component` where the U component is the wind speed from East to West, and the V component the wind speed from South to North.

To get the actual direction (in radians), you'll need the [atan2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2) function: `atan2(V, U)`.