# Wind Speed Map of US

Tags: geospatial, usa, weather

I source wind statistics data that i can use to create Max, Min, Mean wind speed maps for the entire US.

I need to download it as a shapefile, geotiff or geojson.

Comment: duplicate? https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/8957/spatial-wind-direction-speed-data

Comment: Are you looking for point data? Are you creating something similar to https://earth.nullschool.net/

Comment: @BarryCarter yes i want to create raster like that.

Comment: @philshem i couldn't find answer

Comment: https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/10154/1049