# Wind region Data for New Zealand

Tags: data-request, releasing-data, weather

Can anyone please refer me the vector data source of the wind region (LEE MULTIPLIER) of New Zealand as the map attached.
[image: demo]

N.B.There are three data layers in this map-

1. Lee Multiplier
2. Coastal boundary
3. Cities

**I need only layer 1**

Comment: As NZ's weather service www.metservice.com has this data, their website says they provice this kind of data to windfarms: http://about.metservice.com/weather-for-business/energy/

Comment: Hi @Swier, in an effort to answer unanswered questions, can you should post this resource as an answer?

Answer (score 2):

As NZ's weather service www.metservice.com has this data, their website says they provice this kind of data to windfarms: about.metservice.com/weather-for-business

Their open data can be found here: http://about.metservice.com/our-company/about-this-site/open-access-data/

Comment: Other sources: http://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/10380/14881